# How to install Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am interested to learn about the Node.js framework Sails.js. But I want to know how to install it. I want to know how to install it every operating system.

I haven't found any exe version to install it or is there any other way to install it ?

Suggest me how to do it.

Comment: 1. Type "sails.js" into Google and search. 2. Click the first link. 3. Click "Getting Started". 4. Do what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping that you have [Node.js installed](http://jstricks.com/install-node-js/) in your system, you can use this command to install Sails:

```
sudo npm -g install sails
```

To verify you SailsJS installation use this command:

```
sails -v
```

You can follow this helpful tutorial on this: [How to install Sails.js](http://jstricks.com/sailsjs-installation-sailsjs-tutorial/)